# How should I start a Sitecore campaign when the entrance page is an alias?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-dms

We have a site with extensive use of product specific contact forms (Web forms for marketers module), so that almost any page can be considered a landing page. We want to run campaigns that make use of existing pages/forms instead of creating new pages specific to the campaign.
As we want to initiate these campaigns off-line we will be making use of aliases to provide short URLs for printed campaign material.
How can we trigger a campaign when an existing page is viewed under an alias, but not when it's reached from another source (e.g. organic search, internal site link, other campaign)?

Comment: You want to achieve, more or less, what was also discussed in this question, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278414/custom-campaign-url-in-dms-2-0

Comment: @MarkCassidy not quite. I can assign a campaign directly to a content item (typically a landing page), so that the campaign querystring isn't required to trigger the campaign (e.g. mysite.com/products/categories/cool-stuff/product-landing-a). The alias is just a reference to the content item to give a print friendly URL (e.g. mysite.com/product-a). I want to trigger the campaign, without a querystring, only when the landing page is visited under its alias, not when the content item is found some other way (Google, internal search etc.)

Comment: I'm thinking; wouldn't you be able to configure the alias as an External Link, including your campaign trigger querystring?  (sc_camp)  I'm a bit pressed for time right now, so unfortunately I cannot dig in and verify this.

Comment: @MarkCassidy well the point would be to have the alias on a paper brochure as a nice, short, type-able  URL, so I can't quite see how the querystring would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something custom with the AliasResolver pipeline processor.

In this processor you could trigger certain campaigns if a certain alias was accessed.

Here's how to set up an alias resolver:

http://sitecoreblog.patelyogesh.in/2013/08/sitecore-item-alias-alternate-url.html

Also code to trigger campaign is here:

http://www.alen.me.uk/2014/05/trigger-sitecore-dms-campaign-via-ajax.html

A more elegant solution would be to incorporate the rules engine into the logic that determines which alias triggers what campaign. You can do this by following these steps:

1. Add a new Rules field to the alias item in Sitecore by inheriting a new template
2. Add code in the custom AliasResolver to run the rules on the Alias that the AliasResolver resolves - some example code here which uses Outcomes but you could switch this out for Alias items. - 
   https://github.com/ianjohngraham/CoreBlimey.Utils/blob/master/CoreBlimey.OutcomeRules/Pipelines/RunOutcomeRules.cs
3. Add rule actions to each Alias e.g trigger campaign x. There should already be an action in the rules engine to trigger a campaign, if not you can easily write one.

With this set up, when the Alias is resolved the correct campaign can be triggered and it is all configurable within Sitecore.